# How to get all values from loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, get, return-value, tkinter.checkbutton

I created multiple checkbuttons using a for loop from a list of names. Since there are more than 500 names, I wanted to use the for loop instead of typing them one by one. I need to find out which names are selected from these checkbuttons. But no matter what I did, I couldn't get the values of the checkbuttons one by one. In some of my attempts, I got a single numeric value, but I couldn't get a value for each checkbutton. I don't know where I am doing wrong. Can I get each value from inside this loop? Or do I have to write them all one by one?

```
## a list as an example (There are more than 500 people on the original list.)

name_list = ['John Smith', 'Granny Smith', 'Michael Smith', 'Big Smith', 'Hello Smith']

for record in name_list:
    nameVar = IntVar()
    cb_name = Checkbutton(root, text=record, variable=nameVar, bg="white", anchor="w")
    cb_name.pack(fill="both")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a dictionary that contains all record names and their corresponding state (0 for unselected and 1 for selected):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

name_list = ['John Smith', 'Granny Smith', 'Michael Smith', 'Big Smith', 'Hello Smith']
check_dict = {} # This dictionary will contain all names and their state (0 or 1) as IntVar

def getSelected():
  # Check the state of all check_dict elements and return the selected ones as a list
  selected_names = []
  for record in check_dict:
    if check_dict[record].get():
      selected_names.append(record)
  return selected_names

# Create the checkbuttons and complet the check_dict
for record in name_list:
  nameVar = IntVar()
  cb_name = Checkbutton(root, text=record, variable=nameVar, bg="white", anchor="w")
  cb_name.pack(fill="both")
  check_dict[record] = nameVar

# A button to print the selected names
Button(root, text="Show", command=lambda: print(getSelected())).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In my code exemple you can call the `getSelected()` function to get a list of the selected record names.

Comment: You save my day. Thank you so much. I'm looking for the answer for 3 days :) This work great.

Comment: Glad to see this is what you were looking for, please consider to accept this answer if it solved your problem (check mark beside the answer).